# c# - list of objects - group by - get distinct values by key - lambda / linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

i try to get all keys, that have identical values.

data:

```
public class CustItems
    {
        public string CustID { get; set; }
        public string ItemID { get; set; }
    }
List<CustItems> custItems = new List<CustItems>();
// GetData => fill list
custItems.Add(new CustItems { CustID = "1", ItemID = "1" });
```

No of items: 50'000,
No of customers: 2'000

base list contains 2 fields, meaning is, which customer can buy which item

| CustID | ItemID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |

i try to find out, which items can be bought by the same customers

according to the demo-data
item 1 by customers 1,4,5
item 2 by customers 1,2,3,5
item 3 by customers 1,4,5

so item 1 and 3 can be bought by the same customers

couldn't find out, how to solve this in a performant way, using lambda or linq.

appreciate any hint very much! thx a lot!

p.s.
started with something like:

```
var groupedList = from c in custItems
                          group c by c.ItemID into grp
                          select new
                          {
                              ID = grp.Key,
                             
                              CustList = grp.Select(g => g.CustID).ToList()
                          };
```

but after all, the CustList contains all customers by key (ItemID), but couldn't find a good way to find out, which of the keys (=Item) have identical values (=CustList)

Comment: ...and what are you trying to do? Find our which items can be bought by which customers? Find out which customers can buy the same items? What?

Comment: You may consider `GroupBy` and then checking the sets. If performance criteria are serious, you may check for special algorithms of equality checking but the grouping part must be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `CustID` and `ItemID` are strings (not very optimal performace-wise), I came up with the following linq solution:

```
var res = custItems
    .GroupBy(s => s.ItemID)
    .Select(g => new { ItemId = g.Key, Customers = g.Select(i => i.CustID).OrderBy(c => c).Aggregate((c0, c1) => $"{c0},{c1}") })
    .GroupBy(g => g.Customers)
    .Select(g => new { Customers = g.Key.Split(',').ToList(), Items = g.Select(i => i.ItemId).ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

- you first group your list by the `ItemID` to find out all the customers that buy each individual item
- you then create an anonymous type containing the `ItemID` and a set of `CustID`s - I've used string concatenation here, it's the first spot for improvement - converting a set of IDs that can be used for further grouping
- then you group the results by the `CustID`s sets
- and in the end you bring your `CustID` sets back to a list of IDs and store those in an anonymous type containing the list of `CustID`s and list of `ItemID` that this set of customers buy
- finally you convert everything into a list for structured browsing.

Again, combining and splitting the customers (2nd and 4th step) is what can be optimised.

Comment: perfect! - thx a lot - that's what i was looking for!

Comment: Glad I could help. Remember that you'd need to improve this algorithm by developing a set of methods for combining and recombining the customers IDs and preferably not use string as ID. Otherwise you're facing a huge performance impact.